# How to apply for a new job when the only thing on my resume is my current job

Tags: resume, career-development, job-search, salary, job-change

I have a job right now but I want to look for a new job. I've only had one job so far but I don't want them to find out that I'm looking for a new job. Should I include them on my resume? I'm doing fairly well (programming wise) at this company.

They are my only work experience and I never finished college. The only other thing I have is some github projects with around 3-10 stars on the average.

I don't want my current employer to find out but they would be a great reference.

Comment: Just a thought - 1 job on your resume is one job **more** than before you had you _current_ job.

Comment: Most companies will ask for permission before calling anyone.

Answer (score 11):

Most companies don't call your current company until they are in the final hiring stages. They know it could lead to problems.

Yes, include the current job on the resume. Always do this. Otherwise it looks like you were unemployed. In your case it would look like you were never employed.

When the new company does contact the current company they will expect that the current company is unreliable for a recommendation. If they want you gone, but don't hate you, they might praise you. If they want you gone, and hate you, they might trash you. If they don't want you to leave, they might not give a glowing reference. Many companies in fact will just confirm the details: date of employment, and job title.

For a reference you could also use a trusted co-worker. If they are more senior that is better. Even though you didn't finish college you could also use a professor.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you could benefit from utilizing a combination resume to highlight skills and expertise. Combintation resumes work well if you have limited work HX, recently graduated, or are attempting to switch industries and need to demonstrate transferable skills. Consider taking the 3-4 skill sets that you'd like to highlight for your next employer (ie. project management, sales, web development etc..) develop supporting statements/accomplishments or bullets for each skill cluster. At the bottom of the resume, list your current employer and dates. This format will place empahsis on your skills as opposed to your work HX, as a chronological format does.

I agree with Hough above: employers wont conduct employment verification until they're close to hiring. In that case, you may want to consider having a candid discussion with your direct supervisor if you get to the point of being called back for a 2nd interview..

Comment: I have never in over 30 years of employemnt had a potential employer contact my current one.